# scp works from command line but not from shell script - permission denied

Tags: permissions, scp

I'm migrating some home folders from one Linux box to another using scp. I've saved my public key into the destination box's authorized_keys file and the following command works perfectly when I type it at the command line:

```
scp myArch.tar root@myOtherServer:/root/dumps
```

... however when I put this into a script like so...

```
#!/bin/bash
tar -cf /tmp/$1.tar $1; wait
scp /tmp/$1.tar root@myOtherServer:/root/dumps
```

.. and call it by passing a folder name as a parameter, I get the following error.

```
[root@myHost home]# /root/migrate myHomeFolder
Permission denied (publickey).
lost connection
```

Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Can you add an echo $HOME to the script?  I wonder if the script doesn't have the environment variable to let it know where .ssh is.

Comment: I assume you meant export $HOME - still the same error

Comment: I meant "echo" so you could take a look at the value the script thought it was set to.  But forcing the issue works just as well.   I think it might be time to run verbose logging on the server.

Comment: You could also use the -i parameter on the scp command to make absolutely sure it is sending the right private key, and -v to see if there were any issues with it

Answer (score 0):

try executing the script with sudo ./script.sh
may be because you are writing to /root

Comment: Nope. That doesn't work...any why would it anyway? sudo only applies to the local machine - the problem here is the connection to the remote

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely due to the shebang starting a new instance of the bash shell, in which the ssh-agent hasn't been set up. To make sure, you can add the following line to the top of your script:

`ssh-add -l >> $HOME/ssh.log 2>&1`

run the script and check what you get in ssh.o